# This JPQL query behaves differently depending on the inheritance strategy

Tags: java, sql, jpa, orm, jpql

```
select x from Item x
    where treat (x as Book).author = "a"
    or treat (x as Movie).director = "b"
```

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Item {
~~~~~
~~~~~
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class Book extends Item {
    public String author;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("M")
public class Movie extends Item {
    public String director;
}
```

Above JPQL query always does not return any `Item`s.
It inner joins three tables `Item` `Book` and `Movie`, which will result in no data.

When we change the `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)` to
`@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`, the query works well.
I think there is a bug in the JOINED case.

Please let me know if this a bug.

Also, if this is not a bug, please let me know how to fix the query for JOINED.

Comment: Indeed, in SINGLE_TABLE strategy, there will be no join : director and author are in the same table. But could you active sql query log (parameter `hibernate.show_sql`) to see the request for JOINED strategy ?

Comment: JPA 2.1 section 4.4.9 states "That is, in the case of a join, the referenced object does not participate in the result, and in the case of a restriction, the associated predicate is false." This isn't a join so should be treated as false. Example "SELECT e FROM Employee e
WHERE TREAT(e AS Exempt).vacationDays > 10
      OR TREAT(e AS Contractor).hours > 100" which should cover this case exactly. Your JPA provider must be doing inner joins when it should be handling it with outer joins to avoid the restriction. Try another provider and verify